# DAX - Getting previous value

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

hopefully someone can help with this :)

My data is in the following format:

```
Date             Value
01/01/2020       100.00
01/01/2020       12.55
31/01/2020       50.00
02/02/2020       95.65
02/02/2020       1256.00
08/02/2020       62.55
```

I want to return the following in a matrix:

```
Current Date       Current Value      Previous Date     Previous Value
01/01/2020         112.55                                                            
31/01/2020         50.00              01/01/2020        112.55
02/02/2020         1351.65            31/01/2020        50.00
08/02/2020         62.55              02/02/2020        1351.65
```

I have created the following two measures:

```
Previous Date = 
VAR a =
    MAX ( 'Lift Contract History'[Date] )
VAR b =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Lift Contract History'[Date] ),
        FILTER ( ALL('Lift Contract History'), 'Lift Contract History'[Date] < a )
    )
RETURN
    b

Previous Value =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Lift Contract History'[Value] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( 'Lift Contract History' ),
        'Lift Contract History'[Date] = [Previous Date]
    )
)
```

What I am getting is:

```
Current Date       Current Value      Previous Date     Previous Value
01/01/2020         112.55                                                            
31/01/2020         50.00              01/01/2020        
02/02/2020         1351.65            31/01/2020       
08/02/2020         62.55              02/02/2020
```

Is there any way to obtain the previous value by amending my [Previous Value] measure?

Many thanks for all help

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to get the answer:

```
Previous Value New = var prevdate = [Previous Date]
return CALCULATE (
SUM ( 'Lift Contract History'[Value] ),
FILTER (
ALL ( 'Lift Contract History' ),
'Lift Contract History'[Date] = prevdate
)
)
```

In case anyone else needs it. I had to move the PreviousDate measure out of the FILTER and into a variable - inside the FILTER its a different context